# How to Import a variable of my spider class from my pipelines.py file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I found an interesting scraper on github.
https://github.com/apetz/email-scraper

The spider **scrapes** email from a website.

This scraper need to be called by command line with a website as argument:

```
scrapy crawl spider -a domain="your.domain.name" -o emails-found.csv
```

**I would like to edit this scraper in order to store email in my database instead of a json file.**

So I tried to get the "domain" argument located in /spiders/thorough_spider.py in the class "ThoroughSpider".

So in my pipelines.py file, I wrote:

```
 import spiders.thorough_spider
```

in order to import the module thorough_spider which conains the varaible ThoroughSpider.domain

But pycharm is telling me

> "No module named spiders"

.

So I tried this line:

```
 from spiders import thorough_spider
```

And pycharm is telling me this time

> "Unresolved reference "spiders".

Here is the code of the spider thorough_spider.py located in fodler "spiders":

```
class ThoroughSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider"

    def __init__(self, domain=None, subdomain_exclusions=[], crawl_js=False):
        self.allowed_domains = [domain]
        start_url = "http://" + domain

        self.start_urls = [
            start_url
        ]
```

and here is the code in my pipelines.py which is located above the folder "spiders":

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
import mysql.connector

import spiders.thorough_spider
from spiders import thorough_spider
```

**Do you know how can I get the domain passed as argument in my pipelines.py?**

Comment: I'm positive you'll get all the help from the community this time.  I have made some edits and looking in to your problem.

Comment: Going through my repository, I found something you may find useful if you are into web scraping and web crawling stuff  https://medium.com/@gangasivakrishna/how-to-make-a-simple-email-extractor-in-python-889784dfd015

Comment: Thanks @mishsx but I am too newbie to make run your code. The one on your blog post show me a lot of errors. And your github package doesn't have any doc. I need to learn more about python and scraping to be able to use your work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'll suggest you some into level resources, that could be of your help.

Comment: Check this @Cff https://coderwall.com/p/r9urbw/python-web-crawling-for-emails

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. But this tuto is for python 2. I made some changes for python 3 by switching urllib2 by urllib.request. But I get some error log: "TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object".

Comment: Why you can't just `yield` your `domain` variable with the item? This way you'll get it in the `process_item`in your `pipelines.py`

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna import from currently directory module you can use dot `.`

So you can try :

```
from .spiders.thorough_spider import ThoroughSpider
```

it's should be working

Comment: Yes, it did! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from scraper.spiders import thorough_spider
```

or replace 'scraper' with the name of your project

Comment: Thanks @reg202 but I get same error: ""Unresolved reference "spiders". I took this screenshot to be more clear and help you to help me: http://prntscr.com/otk82t

Comment: You're using the settings file from the github including ```SPIDER_MODULES = ['scraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'scraper.spiders'```? And you've commented out the other import lines right? ```from spiders``` and ```import spiders.throrough.....```